# Reading a specific line in Julia

Tags: file, julia, readlines

Since I'm new in Julia I have sometimes obvious for you problems.
This time I do not know how to read the certain piece of data from the file i.e.:

```
...
      stencil: half/bin/3d/newton
      bin: intel
Per MPI rank memory allocation (min/avg/max) = 12.41 | 12.5 | 12.6 Mbytes

Step TotEng PotEng Temp Press Pxx Pyy Pzz Density Lx Ly Lz c_Tr 

  200000    261360.25    261349.16    413.63193    2032.9855    -8486.073    4108.1669    
  200010    261360.45    261349.36    413.53903    22.925126   -29.762605    132.03134   
  200020    261360.25    261349.17    413.46495    20.373081   -30.088775     129.6742   


Loop
```

What I want is to read this file from third row after "Step" (the one which starts at 200010 which can be a different number - I have many files which stars at the same place but from different integer) until the program will reach the "Loop". Could you help me please? I'm stacked - I don't know how to combine the different options of julia to do it...

Comment: I already know that I can use a "readuntil" command to reach "Loop" however I still do not know how to choose a third or second line after "Step".

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution. It uses [`eachline`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.eachline) to iterate over the lines. The loop skips the header, and any empty lines, and breaks when the `Loop` line is found. The lines to keep are returned in a vector. You might have to modify the detection of the header and/or the end token depending on the exact file format you have.

```
julia> function f(file)
           result = String[]
           for line in eachline(file)
               if startswith(line, "Step") || isempty(line)
                   continue # skip the header and any empty lines
               elseif startswith(line, "Loop")
                   break # stop reading completely
               end
               
               push!(result, line)
           end
           return result
       end
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f("file.txt")
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "200000 261360.25 261349.16 413.63193 2032.9855 -8486.073 4108.1669"
 "200010 261360.45 261349.36 413.53903 22.925126 -29.762605 132.03134"
 "200020 261360.25 261349.17 413.46495 20.373081 -30.088775 129.6742"
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. How I can start read from the line "200010" so 3rd line after "Step"? So I imagine that Im reading the file and when I see "Step" I start to read 3 lines later.